# Eclipse menus are slow to render and disappear

Tags: 11.10, menu, eclipse

I have just installed eclipse in Ubuntu 11.10 and I'm noticing the menus (in the application's menubar) are slow to render and disappear. I have not explored many more aspects of the program as this just put me off completely. Is this a known issue and is there anything I can do to fix it as I know eclipse to be a very good application.

Possibly a Java issue?

Comment: Sounds like it could be a graphics/compiz/java three-way bug. What graphics card are you using?

Comment: Radeon HD 6670 - no issues with any other program though. Compiz too.

Comment: You could try installing the oracle jvm/jdk. It tends to have better performance especially in graphics

Comment: I have this issue too. My card is a Radeon HD 4250.

Comment: I'm seeing this also with a freshly downloaded Eclipse version from the Android SDK - badged as ADK but looks like it's based on Eclipse 4.2. Anyhow, I've got a Radeon 5850 card, triple-head setup, using Oracle JDK 1.7, and the menus are drawing very slowly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Eclipse package as shipped by Ubuntu has native window rendering disabled to work around a (now fixed) bug in GDK.

See : https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/eclipse/+bug/769277

I suspect that this may also cause slow rendering, so try this ;

`sudo gedit /usr/bin/eclipse` and remove or comment out the line (with a hash character)

GDK_NATIVE_WINDOWS=true

Comment: I have no `/usr/bin/eclipse`, ubuntu 12.10. I installed from their website, not with `apt`, and actually, there are no installation. Still same problem